# Does Grails 2.3.2 support java8

Tags: grails, java-8, grails-2.3

I have a grails application which is running properly with jdk1.7.0_72 and tomcat-7.0.47

Can I use jdk1.8.0_77 insted of jdk1.7.0_72?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Groovy 2.3 was the [first official version](http://www.groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-2.3.html) to support Java 8.

Your Grails lib folder has the Groovy version it depends on. 
From installs on my machine:

```
grails-2.3.7/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groovy-all-2.1.9.jar
grails-2.4.0/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groovy-all-2.3.1.jar
grails-2.4.3/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groovy-all-2.3.6.jar
grails-2.4.4/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groovy-all-2.3.7.jar
grails-3.0.8/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/groovy-2.4.4.pom
grails-3.1.3/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/groovy-2.4.6.pom
```

So, you need to go to at least Grails 2.4.x